# Line integrals and what do they mean and calculate?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I was trying to solve problem 50 of chapter 5 of the book "Real mathematical analysis" By pugh, and here goes the problem:

Draw a staircase curve $S_n$ that approximates the diagonal
$$\Delta = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2|0 \le x=y \le 1\}$$
to within a tolerance $\frac{1}{n}$. suppose that $f,g: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are smooth.

a) Why does lenght of $S_n$ not converge to the lenght of $\Delta$?

b) Despite (a), prove that

$\int_{S_n}^{}f dx \rightarrow \int_{\Delta} f dx $

Part (a) is trivial but about part (b), if we happen to set $f = 1$ then wouldn't the two integrals calculate the lenghts still?
It seems my confusion is from the "$f dx$" and what does it trully mean on $S_n$ and $\Delta$.

One possible thing that comes to mind is that by $\int_{\Delta} f dx$ we simply mean:

$\int_{0}^{1} f(x,x) dx$

but even knowing this, by setting $f=1$ the first integral would be 1 while the second one would be 2 since each segment has an integral of $\frac 1n$, an explanation that comes to mind again, is that for upward segments of $S_n$ the integral is 0, how ever I don't understand how, is it because "x is not moving"?

thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the integral $\int_C dx$ gives the length of $C$ if and only if $C$ is a positively-oriented line segment parallel to the $x$-axis. You might recall doing line integrals $\int_C  f\,ds$ and $\int_C \vec F\cdot\vec T\,ds$ in your multivariable calculus class; here $ds$ represents arclength along the curve. Pugh assumes you have this knowledge of line integrals from first- or second-year calculus.

When you suspected the answer should be $2$, you meant $\sqrt2$? But, no, it's still $1$ because you're integrating $dx$ and not $ds$. If you parametrize the line segment by $\vec g(t) = (t,t)$, $0\le t\le 1$, then $$\int_\Delta f\,dx = \int_0^1 f(\vec g(t))\frac{dx}{dt}dt = \int_0^1 1\cdot 1\,dt = 1.$$
Indeed, you can think of projecting $\Delta$ onto the interval $[0,1]$ on the $x$-axis, and then $\int_\Delta f\,dx = \int_0^1 f(x,x)\,dx$, in general. If you were integrating $dy$, you could project onto the interval on the $y$-axis; but if you're integrating $ds$, then you do need to think through the parametrization and you get $\int_0^1 f(t,t)(\sqrt2)\,dt$.

Comment: Yeah I do remember those, my problem is with the "dx" because I don't always understand what they are supposed to indicate. 
But thanks for the answer, I understood the problem. (and seems like in my comment I miss wrote "the first" and "the second", care to explain why the same integral on the staircase is equal to 1 aswell?

I think its probably because if we project those "Upward" line segments we get a measure zero set in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If you learn about differential forms, you'll want to evaluate $dx$ on the tangent vector to the curve, and $dx(e_1) = 1$ and $dx(e_2)=0$ (with $e_1$ and $e_2$ the standard orthonormal basis) encapsulates this discussion.